# Java 8 set iterator exclude values

Tags: java, iterator, set

I am iterating through  Set of objects using iterator using streams and creating a List;
I want to remove(ignore) certain elements from the Set while adding to list.
The iterator.hasNext() is behaving very differently.

```
class Object{
    String a;
    String b;

    //getters
    //setters
}



Set<Object> objSet is set of Class Object.
Iterator<Object> iterator = objSet.iterator();
objSet.stream()
    .forEach((Object) -> {
    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
      if( (!iterator.next().equals("111")) || (!iterator.next().equals("222"))){
        data.add(iterator.next().getA());
        data.add(iterator.next().getB());
        returnData.add(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "behaving very differently".  Please include in your question the expected behavior and how this program deviates from that behavior.

Comment: Naming a class called `Object`? Does it really have an `equals` method that matches `java.lang.String`s?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the iterator with lambda expressions.
You could do (with Iterator):

```
Set<Object> objSet = new HashSet<>();
    Iterator<Object> iter = objSet.iterator();

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        Object current = iter.next(); //Important since iter.next() increments index every call
        if("111".equals(current) || "222".equals(current)) continue;
        data.add(current.getA());
        data.add(current.getB());
    }
```

or with Lambda:

```
List<Object> returnData = objSet.stream().filter(o -> (!"111".equals(o) && !"222".equals(o))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Manner, if I go with iterator, how I can data be added as array of arrays. Assuming there is one finalData which is of type List<List<String>>; I want finalData to store value as [[], []]

Comment: You can create a new List in every iteration and add the data you want in it.
At the end of each iteration you just add your created List to the `data` List which needs to be of type `List<List<String>>`